# How can I dynamically set the event handler for a TabItem when it is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

In XAML you can do

```
<TabItem Selector.Selected="myEvenHandler"></TabItem>
```

to set the event handler for when that tab is selected.  How can I do the exact same thing dynamically.  I would prefer not to use the SelectionChanged event of TabControl if I can help it.  Clearly there is a Selected event on the TabItem I just cannot seem to get at it in code.  Here's what I'd like to do.

```
TabItem item = new TabItem();
MyCustomControl mcc = new MyCustomControl();
item.Content = mcc;
item.Selected += (s,e) =>  // This event does not exist
{
    selectedControl = mcc;
}
myTabControl.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for the [Selector.Selected attached event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selected.aspx), in the "C# Syntax" section:

> See [AddSelectedHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.addselectedhandler%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [RemoveSelectedHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.removeselectedhandler%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Their page doesn't actually have hyperlinks to the AddSelectedHandler and RemoveSelectedHandler pages, but they're where you want to look. So your code would look something like:

```
Selector.AddSelectedHandler(item, (s,e) =>
{
    selectedControl = mcc;
});
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, looks like I was missing 
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;